# Error logged in WebKit Web Inspector disappears because of page refresh

Tags: javascript, console, webkit, web-inspector

While hunting a Javascript error related to form submission. I saw an error appear in the Web Inspector then disappear immediately since the form submits and refreshes the page. Is there a console history or scrollback? How can I see what the error is?

Comment: Can you post the submit handler?

Comment: I don't need help tracking the bug (it was looking for a variable that didn't exist) rather I want to learn how to catch errors like this using the Webkit console (or other tools). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Chrome Webkit Console Preserve Log]

**In Chrome**, look for the "Preserve Log" check box in the console.

**In Safari (9+)**, right click in console and select "Keep Log on Navigation".

This was solved awhile back ([Safari Developer Tools: How to Preserve Log Upon Navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572693/safari-developer-tools-how-to-preserve-log-upon-navigation)) but since I encountered the question again I figured I'd include an answer.